# Are the commands ps and top limited to processes?

Tags: linux

If I run the command ps or top, do they only list processes or do they list both services and processes? How do you tell whether a given row represents a process or service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the term [*service*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service) is rarely used in a Linux environment. More common is the term [*daemon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)).

While both terms describe the same kind of application, the term *service* does have some properties attached to it by the use of the term in the Windows environment.

What distinguishes a daemon from a *normal* process is simply that a daemon is a background process and is not interacted with by the user. But what is most important is that the term *daemon* is just that, a term. There is, to my knowledge, no flag in Linux that tells it "*This process is a daemon*".

So daemons aren't in any way special. We just call a certain type of program a daemon.
That's also why there is no distinction being made by `ps` or `top`.

But if you want to know which of your currently running processes is most likely what we think of when thinking of a daemon, try `ps axjf`:

```
oliver@ubuntuServer:~$ ps axjf
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
    0     2     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00 [kthreadd]
    2     3     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:01  \_ [ksoftirqd/0]
    2     5     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [kworker/u:0]
    2     6     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [migration/0]
    2     7     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [migration/1]
    2     9     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [ksoftirqd/1]
    2    10     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:09  \_ [kworker/0:1]
    2    11     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [migration/2]
    2    12     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [kworker/2:0]
    2    13     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [ksoftirqd/2]
    2    14     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [migration/3]
    2    15     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [kworker/3:0]
    2    16     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [ksoftirqd/3]
    2    17     0     0 ?           -1 S<       0   0:00  \_ [cpuset]
    2    18     0     0 ?           -1 S<       0   0:00  \_ [khelper]
    2    19     0     0 ?           -1 S<       0   0:00  \_ [netns]
    2    20     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [kworker/u:1]
    2    21     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [sync_supers]
    2    22     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [bdi-default]
    2    23     0     0 ?           -1 S<       0   0:00  \_ [kintegrityd]
    2    24     0     0 ?           -1 S<       0   0:00  \_ [kblockd]
    2    25     0     0 ?           -1 S<       0   0:00  \_ [ata_sff]
    2    26     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [khubd]
    2    27     0     0 ?           -1 S<       0   0:00  \_ [md]
    2    28     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [khungtaskd]
    2    29     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [kworker/3:1]
    2    30     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:03  \_ [kswapd0]
    2    31     0     0 ?           -1 SN       0   0:00  \_ [ksmd]
    2    32     0     0 ?           -1 SN       0   0:00  \_ [khugepaged]
    2    33     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [fsnotify_mark]
    2    34     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [ecryptfs-kthrea]
    2    35     0     0 ?           -1 S<       0   0:00  \_ [crypto]
    2    43     0     0 ?           -1 S<       0   0:00  \_ [kthrotld]
    2    44     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_0]
    2    45     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_1]
    2    67     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:1]
    2    68     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:09  \_ [kworker/0:2]
    2   110     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:2]
    2   190     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_2]
    2   208     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [kworker/2:1]
    2   218     0     0 ?           -1 S<       0   0:00  \_ [kdmflush]
    2   235     0     0 ?           -1 S<       0   0:00  \_ [kdmflush]
    2   243     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:13  \_ [jbd2/dm-0-8]
    2   244     0     0 ?           -1 S<       0   0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
    2   508     0     0 ?           -1 S<       0   0:00  \_ [kpsmoused]
    2 20477     0     0 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ [flush-252:0]
    0     1     1     1 ?           -1 Ss       0   0:00 /sbin/init
    1   303   302   302 ?           -1 S        0   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
    1   306   306   306 ?           -1 Ss       0   0:00 udevd --daemon
  306   438   306   306 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ udevd --daemon
  306   445   306   306 ?           -1 S        0   0:00  \_ udevd --daemon
    1   562   541   541 ?           -1 Sl     101   0:04 rsyslogd -c5
    1   600   599   599 ?           -1 S        0   0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
    1   612   612   612 ?           -1 Ss     102   0:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork --activation=upstart
```

This is part of the output of a relatively fresh Ubuntu server installation. The output should be hierarchical, which should make it easier to identify system processes.

Like in this part of the same `ps` output. You can clearly see, the chain started with the `sshd` (the SSH daemon), into which I logged in and created a user session for myself. In that, `bash` was started and in bash I have a background `vi` process and my `ps` I just executed.

```
 8053 20352 20352 20352 ?           -1 Ss       0   0:00  \_ sshd: oliver [priv]
20352 20378 20352 20352 ?           -1 S     1000   0:00      \_ sshd: oliver@pts/0
20378 20379 20379 20379 pts/0    20570 Ss    1000   0:00          \_ -bash
20379 20569 20569 20379 pts/0    20570 T     1000   0:00              \_ vi
20379 20570 20570 20379 pts/0    20570 R+    1000   0:00              \_ ps axjf
```

So, looking at those two pieces of `ps` output, you should be able to clearly distinguish between daemons and user processes.

Comment: Thanks. Is it fair or safe to assume then that every application is part of a daemon or can a process run without a daemon?

Comment: There will always be *something else* that starts a process. At the very least, that's the kernel. So, I guess, the answer to your question is dependent on if you consider the kernel to be a daemon.

Comment: When you say it is dependent whether I consider the kernel a daemon, do you mean to say that the use of the term daemon is loose?

Comment: In my personal opinion, yes.

Comment: Some of the sources I read today define a daemon as a process whose parent has the pid `1` (which would be the `init` process). But what about a process that **I** would spawn into the background (some applications have `--daemon` options)? Is that not a daemon? In my personal opinion the term is applied somewhat loosely.

Answer (score 2):

Services are processes, so yes, both are listed by ps. They are just not distinguished clearly. A service is a process that listens for requests or connections.

You can use netstat to list processes that are listening (and which are therefore part of a service)